# Replace exact word with another in shell with tr command

Tags: shell

I want to replace a word with another word in a text file.

file.txt :

```
alireza fallah
```

my code :

```
cat file.txt | tr ali ALI
```

but I get this :

```
ALI fALLAh
```

it replace all 'a's to 'A' , and 'l's to 'L' and 'i's to 'I' .

is there any way to replace just 'ali' to 'ALI' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This task is easier with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -i 's/ali/ALI/' file.txt
```

because `tr` operates on **character sets** rather than **strings**.

To avoid unwanted replacements while echoing, try specifying the exact position of the word to be replaced and or a regular expression that matches only the string you are interested in:

```
$ printf "cali\nali\nwali\nmali.\n" | grep -E '^ali' | tr ali ALI
ALI
```

Comment: thanks , cant it be done by tr ?

Comment: sed -i replaces the word in original file , i just want to echo it

Comment: Well, you Q says:"I want to **replace** a word with another word **in a text file**."

Comment: WELL , excuse me !

Comment: I have added an example using `tr`that doesn't alter the original file.